# Process memory reading always returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory

I've trying to read memory adress(float type).So, it just return 0 in any cases(I've tried int, float etc. memory adress values).In other programs(Cheat Engine) all works.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

DWORD adresss = 0x00179574;
DWORD pid;
float id;



int main()
{
    HWND game = FindWindowA(0, ("Window name"));
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(game, &pid);
    HANDLE maincs = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    for (;;)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(maincs, (void*)adresss, &id, sizeof(int), 0);

        std::cout << id << std::endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not checking return codes. Maybe the window was not found or your handle could be invalid. ReadProcessMemory can fail. Also the address can change because ASLR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are reading the value of an `int` from the process, but saving it as a `float`. Try to change it to `sizeof(float)`. Also, make `address` `LPVOID`, instead of casting it to a void pointer.

If it still fails, there is one more thing. The address you seem to be reading seems too small. A common address in the process will be like `0x7ff6d91c0000`.

Also, you don't need `<Process.h>`, and the last address of `ReadProcessMemory` should be `nullptr` instead of `0`.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` are the same on Windows. The address looks perfectly fine for a 32-bit process. This is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows API calls to see if they are failing:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


LPVOID adresss = (LPVOID)0x00179574;
DWORD pid;
float id;

int main()
{
    HWND game;
    HANDLE maincs;

    if ((game = FindWindowA(0, ("Window name"))))
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(game, &pid);
        if ((maincs = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid)))
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                if (ReadProcessMemory(maincs, adresss, &id, sizeof(float), 0))
                {
                    std::cout << id << std::endl;
                }
                else std::cout << "ReadProcessMemory failed with : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

                Sleep(100);
            }
            CloseHandle(maincs);
        }
        else std::cout << "OpenProcess failed with : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "FindWindowA failed with : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    std::string dummy;
    std::cin >> dummy;
    return 0;
}
```

tell us what it prints out or if it worked